# Apache Stops Responding After Putting Files Inside htdocs Folder

Tags: apache, htdocs

I have a folder which contains html, js, css and font files. I placed that folder inside the apache htdocs folder. For first 5 minutes it is working fine, but after that apache is not responding to external request. I can access the website from localhost and not through 127.0.0.1. I am using apache 2.4 in windows server 2012.

Answer (score 0):

Its strange, the problem its could be in your conection. Try to check FireWall

Comment: Firewall is not the problem, I have checked that